# How to use NSUserDefaults and UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification to store the present state of Application when the user Logs Out?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsuserdefaults

I have a requirement to store the present state of application using **UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification** and **NSUserDefaults** where i need to load the application with the previous state when the user has logged out from the Application. My application is a TabBar Based Application and inturn its a Navigation Controller. I need to store the present view controller loaded in the navigation Controller and the present tab where the Navigation Controller is present. My application works for different user and i need to store the state of the application particular to the user. So, i need to store the user data as well. I searched it in StackOverflow and Googled it to find that we need to use something like **NSUserDefaults** and **UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification** is necessary for the same. This is the first time i am coming across these stuff. Can someone please post some tutorial or any sample code on how to get my requirement done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register for the notifications themselves (see NSNotificationCenter) and write your save/load code there, or you can put your code in the AppDelegate, which provides these hooks:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions;
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application;
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application;
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application;
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application;
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application;
```

Look in the AppDelegate.m file, and you can see stub implementation with some documentation as to how they are to be used.

In there, you will simply write your data to, and read it from NSUserDefaults, as appropriate.

```
// Store the data
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:fooObject forKey:@"Foo"];
[defaults setObject:barObject forKey:@"Bar"];
[defaults synchronize];

// Load the data
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *fooObject = [defaults objectForKey:@"Foo"];
NSString *barObject = [defaults objectForKey:@"Bar"];
```

Comment: I'm sorry, what else do you need?  Really, that's all there is to saving/loading user defaults.  And as far as knowing when to do it, you can just drop the save/load stuff into the appropriate app delegate methods.  It kick starts your app anyway, so having it load the user defaults makes sense.  Maybe I could provide more, if I knew what you are having a hard time with...

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you know the usage of `NSUserDefaults`. For this specific task, you just need to save the state of :

1. Tab bar controller - Get the `selectedIndex` for the current tab and save that in userDefaults.
2. NavigationController of that tab - as you would know , the navigation controller is nothing but the view controller in that `navigationArray`. You just need to get the `index` of that view controller, and store that in the `userDefaults`.

That's pretty much it. You will need to save them (along with other user's unsaved data) in the `UIApplicationWillTerminate` and that should save them. Remember to `synchronize` userDefaults to force the save. :)

Comment: Sample code ? Its pretty straight forward. Please look at examples for NSUserDefaults usage.